# Multiple Selection Combobox

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a scenario where there is a combobox with checkboxes, so multiple selection is possible. After selecting the combobox items, I need to execute an update query. I know to write the query for single item, but how to do the query for multiple selections from combobox.

Regards,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

The combobox shows items based on a list of view models, lets name them CheckableViewModel in the view model that is the data context of te view:

```
class ViewModel
{
    //...
    List<CheckableItemViewModel> Items;
    //...
}

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          <!-- more properties --> />
```

As far as querying data is a task done in the data logic this task has also to be triggered there. This means that your CheckableItemViewModel has to signal a change of it's checked state, e.g. via an event (at least PropertyChanged on property Checked). The view model that contains the list of CheckableItemViewModels, which is the view model the UI binds to, has to listen for this event. And this view model has to contain the logic to call the appropriate query containing the appropriate data.